# Populating SQLDataSource from Sessions in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the below code and I am trying to make the connection string as well as the parameters that the pass to the stored procedure use values stored in a session. How can this be done?

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlds" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%# Session("ConnStrEP") %>" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="GetGenInfo_Mines">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="6" Name="RevNo" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1003992" Name="AppNo" Type="String" />

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to pass a session parameter can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx

Comment: That solves one problem, but how do I make my ConnectionString in the sqlDataSource control use a session value?

Comment: I managed to fix this by assigning a value to the gridviewname.connectionstring in the page load using my session variable